Manhwa with a pink-haired girl who wields a sword and wants revenge against her father
I don't remember it very well, but the plot goes like this:
A girl is sent as a child by her asshole father to another dimension where she survived and trained. When she returns, the asshole father denies that she is his daughter and tries to kill her. She also has a younger brother.
The girl wants revenge on her father.
(Also, there was a queen with white or silver hair who also survived in another dimension.)

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Is this Regina Rena: To the Unforgiven...?

Rena Rubel is a beautiful woman who has faced her share of hardships, as she was offered as a sacrifice by her own father, Marquis Rubel. She manages to survive and one day encounters a man named Lin, who belatedly discovers she is a powerful warrior who can hold her own. Rena gifts him with the elusive altar stone, and he promises to pay her back. They agree to meet again, and she continues to travel with her maid Yuni, seeking her father for his sins of the past. Can he be forgiven?


The day before her twelfth birthday, the pink-haired protagonist, Rena, was sold by her father, Marquis Cardo Rubel, to the Western Duke, Clavis Silentium Grasha, who cast her into a dimension known as the Land of the Dead or the Grave, hoping she would return with holy powers as the silver-haired Empress, Nihil Grasha, once did.
In the Grave, Rena, encountered a statue-like being who introduced herself as King Regina, the Unforgiven. Regina took Rena under her wing and taught her many things, including swordsmanship.
Six years later, Rena returns to the world of the living as a skilled swordswoman. She wants her father to officially acknowledge her as Rena, whom most people believe to be dead, but he refuses to do so as it would reveal his crime, so he claims she's a fraud and tries to kill her. She has a younger brother named Engy, who is unaware of what their father did to her.
You can read the full manhwa at WEBTOON.
